# For civil or passenger airplane, is any moment that left and right elevator activated differently?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, horizontal-stabilizer, elevator, skid

[image: Airbus A380's empennage]

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabilizer_(aeronautics))

I want to know if any moment that the left and right elevator are activated (used/functioned) differently of a civil or passenger airplane. Here I am talking about civil airplane, not a fighter jet. I.e., one (side) elevator is pulled up/down while another elevator of another side remain "neutral" or neither pulled up nor pulled down. If any, when or in what condition?

Comment: Don't have the time to type this up, so will comment rather than answer (but somebody else is welcome to): https://flightinfo.com/threads/dc-9-split-elevator.69703/ and https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=74675  and https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/6567073

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no situation where left and right elevators are *intentionally* deflected differently in any civil aircraft.  (I assume that the "ruddervators" of V-tailed airplanes don't count!)

Comment: Do any commercial planes have single sided trim tabs? Certainly some GA planes do.

Comment: @tedder42 Transport category aeroplanes typically use a [THS (trimmable horizontal stabilizer)](https://www.skybrary.aero/articles/trimmable-horizontal-stabiliser), not trim tabs.

Comment: Yes, I am talking common airplane that their tail is like in the picture which they has vertical and horizontal stabilizer. V-tail or inverted V-tail, or other similar is not included.

Comment: @tedder42, I don't really understand you you mentioned. As my question, if any moment that left and right elevator activated differently, when or in what condition?

Comment: @aircraftlover I don't know what categories either be included under "common airplane" but thanks bianfable, didn't know for sure if large commercial/transport had anything single sided.

Comment: Some Boeing aircraft can have split controls iirc, where if enough force is applied the left seat controls the left elevator and vice versa

Answer (score 4):

Just to add something to @quietflyer answer.

[This is the schematics of the B747's hydraulic system](https://www.quora.com/On-Boeing-747-400-hydraulics-system-what-will-happen-if-one-of-four-system-fails-in-flight-Would-you-explain-to-me-in-details-along-with-its-schematic-diagram/answer/Tim-Morgan-5?ch=15&oid=63918312&share=39da12db&target_type=answer):

[image: Boeing 747 hydraulic system schematic]

For safety reasons it is quadruple-redundant, with each moving surface split into two parts each driven by one or two different systems. As visible, the following connection exist for the elevators:

- left outboard elevator $\rightarrow$ 1
- left inboard elevator $\rightarrow$ 1+2
- right inboard elevator $\rightarrow$ 3+4
- right outboard elevator $\rightarrow$ 4

So, in case of failure of systems 1 and 2 (or 3 and 4) an asymmetrical movement of the elevators could actually happen.

Comment: That is true in case of failure. But failure means, no more option rather than have to do the available option. What I am asking is in an operation which no failure.

Comment: @AirCraftLover: "What I am asking is in an operation which no failure". Sorry it was not clear from you question.